# Same sized wheel menu for different devices?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am Using a Wheel Menu in my App from GAMA http://developer.digitalaria.com/devguide/gama/en/gama/wheel_android.php

I have set the Diameter of the wheel as 400.But the menu is displayed in different sizes.
I want it to display as the no.1 but it displays in some devices as no.1 and some devices as no.2

How can i achieve this same size as no.1 in all devices ?

[image]

```
private void init()
{
    res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
    wheel = (Wheel) findViewById(R.id.wheel);

    wheel.setItems(getDrawableFromData(icons));
    wheel.setWheelDiameter(400);
}
```

XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

 <com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.Wheel
        android:id="@+id/wheel"!
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.Wheel>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use the resources. You can create dimens file for different dimesion of the devices and mention the size of the wheel in specific dimens file.

Comment: @Sripathi integer are not allowed as dimens

Comment: I used it

 <dimen name="key">20dp</dimen>

Comment: @Sripathi See in the Init()method. I need to change the Diameter according to the diff sizes

Comment: Yes what I'm coming to say is, you need to create separate dimens.xml according to the dimension of the device. For example, you need to create values-xhdpi, and a dimens.xml file within it. In xml file you can mention the dimesion of the wheel in dp(as I mentioned above). You can get the value by getResources().getDimension(id); then you can set this value in your wheel. You need to do the same for mdpi, hdpi, xxhdpi and others.

Answer (score 1):

values-mdpi:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="diameter">400dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

values-hdpi:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="diameter">450dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

values-xhdpi:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="diameter">500dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and others..(for the values you can use the values which fits for your wheel)

```
private void init()
{
    res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
    wheel = (Wheel) findViewById(R.id.wheel);

    wheel.setItems(getDrawableFromData(icons));
    wheel.setWheelDiameter(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.diameter));
}
```

The key of the dimension element need to be same. So there will be different values according to the screen dimension, and the needed one will be fetched.